# Webcrawler doesn't work in RapidMiner 9.2, any idea why?

Tags: web-crawler, rapidminer

I am a newbie in Rapid Miner especially for the Webcrawler (Crawl Web). I learned the examples from the existing post in any forum but it seems that Web Crawler in Rapid Miner 9.2 does not work properly as it gives blank result in my machine. This is one of the examples,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="9.2.000">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="9.2.000" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <parameter key="logverbosity" value="init"/>
    <parameter key="random_seed" value="2001"/>
    <parameter key="send_mail" value="never"/>
    <parameter key="notification_email" value=""/>
    <parameter key="process_duration_for_mail" value="30"/>
    <parameter key="encoding" value="SYSTEM"/>
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="web:crawl_web_modern" compatibility="9.0.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Crawl Web X" width="90" x="112" y="85">
        <parameter key="url" value="https://www.dw.com/search/en?searchNavigationId=9097&languageCode=en&origin=gN&item=brexit"/>
        <list key="crawling_rules">
          <parameter key="follow_link_with_matching_url" value=".+search.+"/>
          <parameter key="follow_link_with_matching_url" value=".+news.+"/>
          <parameter key="store_with_matching_url" value=".+brexit.+"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="max_crawl_depth" value="10"/>
        <parameter key="retrieve_as_html" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="enable_basic_auth" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="add_content_as_attribute" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="write_pages_to_disk" value="true"/>
        <parameter key="include_binary_content" value="false"/>
        <parameter key="output_dir" value="/Users/iqbalakbar/Desktop"/>
        <parameter key="output_file_extension" value="html"/>
        <parameter key="max_pages" value="20"/>
        <parameter key="max_page_size" value="1000"/>
        <parameter key="delay" value="0"/>
        <parameter key="max_concurrent_connections" value="100"/>
        <parameter key="max_connections_per_host" value="50"/>
        <parameter key="user_agent" value="rapidminer-web-mining-extension-crawler"/>
        <parameter key="ignore_robot_exclusion" value="false"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Crawl Web X" from_port="example set" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Appreciate your comments and feedbacks. Thank you.

Iqbal

Answer (score 0):

the web crawling operator has some issues, take a look at the RapidMiner community where others had similar issues [1].

The current work around is to use "Get Page" in combination with a loop operator  as described here: [2]

Hope that helps.

[1] https://community.rapidminer.com/discussion/55201/web-crawling-of-https-pages-not-working-by-using-crawl-web

[2] https://community.rapidminer.com/discussion/54662/how-can-i-crawl-more-than-one-web-page